# What the difference between "Urls" and "Endpoints" in Kestrel settings?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration, kestrel-http-server

In ASP Net core web application, you can set which URL the application will listen in two different ways inside the appsettings.json:

1)

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:9999"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. 

```
{
  "Urls": "http://localhost:9999"  
}
```

What are the differences between both approaches and why they exist?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, both “Urls” and “Endpoints” is used to configure endpoints for the ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server.

The urls host configuration key have the limitations.(a default certificate must be available for HTTPS endpoint configuration).

But if you use the Endpoints points, you could have multiple endpoints settings with each own certificate.

Besides, the Url parameter in Endpoints is required for each endpoint. **These endpoints replace those defined in the top-level Urls configuration rather than adding to them. Endpoints defined in code via Listen are cumulative with the endpoints defined in the configuration section.**

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: But...why do they exist? I mean, "Endpoints" are more robust, it would be enough to have just one setting for the purpose, but curiously they implemented two different ones.